# PyCharm "Failed to connect to" SSH server with proxyjump

Tags: ssh, proxy, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, ssh-tunnel

I'm struggling to connect PyCharm to a remote SSH server.

In my Linux command line, I can connect to the server easily, But it seems PyCharm can't!

I have the `.ssh/config` file like this:

```
Host merkur
  Hostname "server"
  User zahra
  Port 22
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/merkurKey

Host t400-208n5
  Hostname "server"
  User zahra
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/merkurKey
  ProxyJump merkur
```

This is the full error:

```
Cannot connect to remote host: net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportException: Server closed connection during identification exchange
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, JetBrains does not support ProxyJump as of right now (April 2023).
But you can easily fix it by changing `ProxyJump merkur` (the last line) to this:

```
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p merkur
```

P.s: I hope you understand `merkur` is just the name of my host. Yours is probably different.